# How to check mysql event status

Tags: mysql

How to check event scheduler status in MySQL database?

I want to know the running status of my event whether it is running or not?

Answer (score 1):

> how to check event scheduler status

It can be ON or OFF (TRUE/FALSE, 1/0) and can be viewed by

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler;
-- or
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

for example.

---

> i want to know the running status of my event whether it is running or not

This is **absolutely** another task. Event scheduler != Event.

Look at

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

for your event executing thread row is present or not.